# Cannot convert null or undefined to object when using hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, lambda, anonymous-function, hasownproperty

I am trying to use `hasOwnProperty` in a more elegant way.

I have this code here, which works fine:

```
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 7,
    bamboo: 22
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));

// keys: [ "a", "b", "bamboo" ]
```

However when I try to pass `obj.hasOwnProperty` as shorthand (which should work), it doesn't behave how I expect.

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(obj.hasOwnProperty);

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
//     at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
```

To ensure that the parameter is passed to `hasOwnProperty` correctly, I have set up this test case:

```
var testFilter = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
    return true;
};

Object.keys(x).filter(testFilter);
```

`a`, `b` and `bamboo` are all logged to the console, so I know that it is passing the parameters correctly.

Why does the behaviour not work correctly for `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: btw, keys returns always properties which are own properties of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object.hasOwnProperty` takes the object as its `this` value. When you do direct calls, this is implicitly provided by looking at what object the method is called *on*, but with indirect calls, you have to specify `this` manually:

```js
var obj = { foo: 3 };
var func = obj.hasOwnProperty;

console.log(func('foo')); // TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

One of the easiest way to do this is with `function.bind`, like this:

```js
var obj = { foo: 3 };
var func = obj.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj); // bind `this` of function to `obj`
console.log(func('foo')); // = true
```

Answer (score 2):

For a correct callback, you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the object to `hasOwnProperty` and then use the returned function.

```js
var obj = {
        a: 2,
        b: 7,
        bamboo: 22
    },
    keys = Object.keys(obj).filter({}.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj));

console.log(keys);
```